# A Python return value

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a bisect function that takes a word list "t" and a word "val". It recursively halves the list until the index of the list is the word or returns false.  If it finds the word, it is supposed to return it.

I have read multiple books, the documentation, and all the applicable questions here on SO but I still cannot determine what I am doing wrong: why won't the function return the value? It will print the value just fine, but no return except None.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def bisect(t, val):
    if t[len(t)/2] < val and len(t) > 1:
        t = t[len(t)/2:]
        bisect(t, val)
    elif t[len(t)/2] > val and len(t) > 1:
        t = t[:len(t)/2]
        bisect(t, val)
    elif t[len(t)/2] == val:
        t = t[len(t)/2]
        #print type(t), t
        return t
    else:
        return False

b = make_list(t)
x = bisect(b, 'and')
print x
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `return bisect(..)` when performing the recursive calls?

Comment: If I put a print statement after `if` and the first `elif`, it prints the (half) list correctly until it finds the value. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you need to return `t` from each call to the recursively called function. Picture the call stack using my modified code below:

```
def main():
    b = ['a', 'able', 'ability', 'abort', 'and', 'arc', 'zygote']
    x = bisect(b, 'and')
    print x



def bisect(t, val):
    if t[len(t)/2] < val and len(t) > 1:
        t = t[len(t)/2:]
        t = bisect(t, val)
    elif t[len(t)/2] > val and len(t) > 1:
        t = t[:len(t)/2]
        t = bisect(t, val)
    elif t[len(t)/2] == val:
        t = t[len(t)/2]
        print type(t), t
    else:
        return False

    return t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first time bisect is called, t is set to `['abort', 'and', 'arc', 'zygote']`. 
On the second call to bisect, t is set to `['abort', 'and']`
On the third call, we have `'and'` located, and return that value.

**IF** you returned as you had (only returning from the exact match or False result), then you return to the second call (`['abort', 'and']`), then the first call (`['abort', 'and', 'arc', 'zygote']`), and finally you return **without hitting a `return t`** in that first call. Thus, nothing is returned.

Rewriting your original code as I have, everything is the same until we find the match. However, with my code, the final call returns `t` back into the `t` variable used in the second call. That returns the value to the first call, which returns the result back to the calling code.

Hopefully, that clears up your question.

Comment: There is one trivial case. If your original example had the target word in the exact middle of the list, then it would return the match correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This modified version works:

```
def bisect(t, val):
    mid = len(t)//2
    mid_ele = t[mid]
    end = len(t)
    if mid_ele < val and end > 1:
        t = t[mid:]
        return bisect(t, val)
    elif mid_ele > val and end > 1:
        t = t[:mid]
        return bisect(t, val)
    elif mid_ele == val:
        t = mid_ele
        return t
    else:
        return False

b = ['she', 'he', 'you', 'and', 'me']
print(bisect(b, 'and'))
```

prints the desired:

```
and
```

I made it Python 3 proof using `//` for integer division and added two `returns`before the recursive call.

Comment: Understood.  And my apologies: the `b = make_list(t)` calls this:

`t = open('list.txt')`

`def make_list(t):`
    `a = []`
    `for line in t:`
        `word = line.strip()`
        `a.append(word)`
    `return a`

The list prints fine when `b` is called.